# What are all the blocks that can face a specific direction in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know for a fact that you can make Hay Bales, Wood blocks, and Pillar Quartz face a specific direction, but are there any more blocks with this capability? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Minecraft, block orientation can be saved as a block's metadata value or some sort of additional data inside a tile entity. There is no *standard* method to do so, though most blocks use some bits of their metadata value for their orientation. Some of them have different orientations, but it is calculated automatically.

A full list of such data is available at the Minecraft wiki in the "[Data Values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values/Pre-flattening#Data)" article. From the article, the following blocks can have a specific orientation:

- flowing [water](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water) and [lava](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lava) (the orientation is automatically calculated by the game). *Stationary* water and lava have no orientation.
- [Anvils](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil) (orientation in the lowest bit of the metadata value)
- [Beds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Buttons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Button) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Chests](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Cocoas](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cocoa_Beans) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Dispensers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dispenser) (orientation in the lowest three bits of the metadata value)
- [Doors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Door) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value of the bottom part *and* the lowest one bit of the upper part)
- [Droppers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dropper) (orientation in the lowest three bits of the metadata value)
- [End Portal Blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Portal_(block)) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Fence Gates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence_Gate) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Fences](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence) (orientation calculated automatically)
- [Furnaces](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Furnace) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Glass Panes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass_Pane) (orientation calculated automatically)
- [Hay Bales](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hay_Bale) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Heads](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Head) (orientation in the metadata value if on the wall, in the tile entity if on the floor)
- [Hoppers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hopper) (orientation in the lowest three bits of the metadata value)
- [Huge Mushroom](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mushroom_Block) blocks (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Iron Bars](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Bars) (orientation calculated automatically)
- [Ladders](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ladder) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Levers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lever) (orientation in the lowest three bits of the metadata value)
- Pillar [Blocks of Quartz](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Quartz) (orientation in the metadata value; the three possible ones correspond to values 2, 3 and 4; values of 0 and 1 create non-orientated different blocks of quartz)
- [Pistons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piston) and Piston Extensions (orientation in the lowest three bits of the metadata value)
- [Pumpkins](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pumpkin) and [Jack'o'Lanterns](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Jack_o%27Lantern) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value, with a special case of metadata = 4 meaning "no face/orientation")
- [Pumpkin Stems](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pumpkin_Seeds) and [Melon Stems](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Melon_Seeds) (orientation automatically calculated)
- [Rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rail) (orientation in the lowest three bits of the metadata value for special rails, in all the bits of the metadata value for regular rails - that's why powered rails are always straight or angled, never making a turn)
- [Redstone Repeaters](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Redstone Wire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Dust) (orientation calculated at runtime)
- [Single Slabs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slab) orientation - upper or lower part of a block - in the highest bit of the metadata value)
- free-standing [Sign Posts](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Stairs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stairs) (orientation partially in the metadata value; connecting "corner" stairs' orientation calculated automatically)
- [Torches](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Torch) and [Redstone Torches](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Torch) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Trapdoors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trapdoor) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Tripwire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/String#Redstone_component) (orientation automatically calculated)
- [Tripwire Hooks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tripwire_Hook) (orientation in the lowest two bits of the metadata value)
- [Vines](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vines) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Wall Signs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign) (orientation in the metadata value)
- [Wood](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wood) (orientation in the highest-order two bits of the metadata value)

---

Answer written for version: **1.6.2**

Comment: I would also add string.If you want 1.9, you have the dragon head, end rods, purpur pillers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is the list of blocks that can be placed in different directions:

- *Hay Bale
- Jack-o-Lantern/Pumpkin
- *Stairs
- Rail (Activator/Booster/Normal)
- Button
- *Lever
- Redstone Comparator/Repeater
- *Wood Logs
- Chest (Ender/Trapped/Normal)
- *Dispenser/Dropper
- *Piston / Sticky Piston
- Door
- Sign
- Ladder/Vines
- Anvil
- Bed
- Fence gate
- Tripwire Hook
- *Nether Quartz Pillar
- Cocoa
- Portal Block

The ones marked with a "*" can be turned in all six directions.

Comment: Wood blocks have only three visibly different ones though (no idea how it's coded)

Comment: Wood logs and some others only have north/south, east/west and up/down; although it's pretty much all you need. Some more like signs, doors (Wood+iron), torches, ladder, furnace, hoppers, trapdoor, vines, end portal block, tripwire hook and anvil could also be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a little bit since Minecraft 1.6, the version the accepted answer was written for. Minecraft 1.8 introduced block states and replaced tile entities with block entities, then the "Flattening" in 1.13 changed a lot of block states to make them more consistent. You can find a full list of block states and the blocks that use them in the Minecraft wiki's article on [Java edition data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values#Block_states).

There's still a few different block states used for direction, which matters for making custom block models. Here's the relevant states used for some form of direction, as of 1.18:

| State | Allowed Values | Blocks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `axis`: axis of alignment | `x`, `y`, `z` | [basalt](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Basalt), [bone block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Block), [chain](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chain), [deepslate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Deepslate), [hay bale](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hay_Bale), [log](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Log), [purpur pillar](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Purpur_Block), [quartz pillar](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Quartz), [wood](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wood) |
| `axis` | `x`, `z` | [nether portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Portal_(block)) |
| `facing`: direction the block is facing | `up`, `down`, `east`, `north`, `south`, `west` | [amethyst cluster](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Amethyst_Cluster), [barrel](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrel), [command block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block), [dispenser](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dispenser), [dropper](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dropper), [end rod](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Rod), [lightning rod](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lightning_Rod), [observer](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Observer), [piston](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piston), [shulker box](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shulker_Box) |
| `facing`: direction the output points | `down`, `east`, `north`, `south`, `west` | [hopper](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hopper) |
| `facing` | `east`, `north`, `south`, `west` | [anvil](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil), [banner](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Banner) (wall), [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed), [beehive/bee nest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beehive), [bell](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bell), [small](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Small_Dripleaf)/[big](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Big_Dripleaf) dripleaf (and stem), [button](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Button), [campfire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Campfire), [carved pumpkin](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pumpkin), [chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest)/[ender chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest)/[trapped chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trapped_Chest), [cocoa pod](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cocoa_Beans), [coral fan](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coral_Fan) (wall), [door](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Door), [end portal frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Portal_Frame), [fence gate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence_Gate), [furnace](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Furnace)/[blast furnace](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blast_Furnace)/[smoker](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Smoker), [glazed terracotta](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glazed_Terracotta), [grindstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Grindstone), [head](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Head) (wall), [jack o'lantern](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Jack_o%27Lantern), [ladder](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ladder), [lectern](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lectern), [lever](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lever), [loom](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loom), [melon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Melon_Seeds)/[pumpkin](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pumpkin_Seeds) stem (attached), [redstone comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Comparator), [redstone repeater](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater), [sign](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign) (wall), [stairs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stairs), [stonecutter](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stonecutter), [torch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Torch)/soul torch/[redstone torch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Torch) (wall), [trapdoor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trapdoor), [tripwire hook](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tripwire_Hook) |
| `open`: only changes direction for doors/trapdoors | `false`, `true` | [barrel](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrel), [door](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Door), [fence gate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence_Gate), [trapdoor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trapdoor) |
| `rotation`: granular direction | `0`–`15` | [banner](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Banner) (floor), [head](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Head) (floor), [sign](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign) (floor) |
| `shape`: how to connect with neighbor blocks | `north_east`, `north_west`, `south_east`, `south_west`, `ascending_east`, `ascending_north`, `ascending_south`, `ascending_west`, `east_west`, `north_south` | [rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rail) |
| `shape` | `ascending_east`, `ascending_north`, `ascending_south`, `ascending_west`, `east_west`, `north_south` | [activator rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Activator_Rail), [detector rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Detector_Rail), [powered rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail) |
| `shape` | `inner_left`, `inner_right`, `outer_left`, `outer_right`, `straight` | [stairs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stairs) |
| `orientation`: direction of arrows, then line face | `down_east`, `down_north`, `down_south`, `down_west`, `east_up`, `north_up`, `south_up`, `up_east`, `up_north`, `up_south`, `up_west`, `west_up` | [jigsaw block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Jigsaw_Block) |
| `vertical_direction` | `up`, `down` | [pointed dripstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pointed_Dripstone) |
| `down`, `up`, `east`, `north`, `south`, `west`: indicates where neighboring blocks are | `false`, `true` | [chorus plant](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chorus_Plant) (how the block extends from the center), [glow lichen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glow_Lichen) (which sides have lichen), [mushroom block/stem](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mushroom_Block) (which sides don't show spores) |
| `up`, `east`, `north`, `south`, `west` | `false`, `true` | [fire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire) (which sides have fire), [vines](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vines) (which sides have vines), [wall](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wall) (how the block extends from the center) |
| `east`, `north`, `south`, `west`: how the block extends from the center | `false`, `true` | [fence](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence), [glass pane](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass_Pane), [iron bars](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Bars), [tripwire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/String) |
| `east`, `north`, `south`, `west` | `none`, `side`, `up` | [redstone wire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Dust) |